# Prestashop custom admin module draggable sort/order not working

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm building a very simple module for Prestashop 1.6 and I added an admin interface that allows to list my records, a form to add and edit and delete.

This is working fine as you can see here:
[image]

The problem is that draggable reorder button is not draggable. Hence the reordering is not working...

According to the [official docs](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperList+class), if you set the position option in your controller, you get the draggable functionality:

```
['position'] => 'position', // If set to position, the field will display arrows and be drag and droppable, which will update position in db (optional).
```

This is the relevant part of my module controller:

```
$this->fields_list = array(
        'id_quicklinks' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('ID'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'width' => 25
        ),
        'titulo' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Titulo'),
            'width' => 'auto'
        )
        , 'lead' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Subtitulo'),
            'width' => 'auto'
        ), 
        'position' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Ordem'),
            'filter_key' => 'a!position',
            'position' => 'position',
            'align' => 'center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-md'
        ),
        'active' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Publicado'),
            'width' => '25',
            'active' => 'status'
        )
    );
```

As you can see in the print screen, is shows the handles but the drag-an-drop doesn't work. No javascript errors on the console, no nothing... And I can see in the source code that jQuery and jQueryUI are loaded. Other admin pages with reorder feature are working fine...

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if anyone is interested, I managed to get this to work.

In my module admin controller, I've added (before the __construct method, right after opening the Class):

```
protected $position_identifier = 'id_quicklinks';
```

- `id_quicklinks` is the primary key of the database table this module uses.

This enabled the drag and drop feature that I was looking for, but altough I could now drag and drop, the order was not saved in the database.

For that to work I've added two more methods adapted from the `controllers/admin/AdminCarriersController.php` and `classes/Carrier.php`:

```
public function ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()
    {
        $way = (int)Tools::getValue('way');
        $id_quicklinks = (int)Tools::getValue('id');
        $positions = Tools::getValue('quicklinks');

        if (is_array($positions))
            foreach ($positions as $position => $value)
            {
                $pos = explode('_', $value);

                if (isset($pos[2]) && (int)$pos[2] === $id_velcroquicklinks)
                {
                        if (isset($position) && $this->updatePosition($way, $position, $id_quicklinks))
                            echo 'ok position '.(int)$position.' for id '.(int)$pos[1].'\r\n';
                        else
                            echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "Can not update id '.(int)$id_quicklinks.' to position '.(int)$position.' "}';

                    break;
                }
            }

    }
```

And:

```
public function updatePosition($way, $position, $id)
    {

        if (!$res = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
            SELECT `id_quicklinks`, `position`
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
            ORDER BY `position` ASC'
        ))
            return false;

        foreach ($res as $quicklinks)
            if ((int)$quicklinks['id_quicklinks'] == (int)$id)
                $moved_quicklinks = $quicklinks;

        if (!isset($moved_quicklinks) || !isset($position))
            return false;
        var_dump($moved_quicklinks['position']);
        // < and > statements rather than BETWEEN operator
        // since BETWEEN is treated differently according to databases
        return (Db::getInstance()->execute('
            UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
            SET `position`= `position` '.($way ? '- 1' : '+ 1').'
            WHERE `position`
            '.($way
                ? '> '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['position'].' AND `position` <= '.(int)$position
                : '< '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['position'].' AND `position` >= '.(int)$position.'
            '))
        && Db::getInstance()->execute('
            UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
            SET `position` = '.(int)$position.'
            WHERE `id_quicklinks` = '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['id_quicklinks']));
    }
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solution.

It took me quite a long time to realize that `ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()` is somehow call by itself. For those struggling to implement that method, note that `echo` and `var_dump()` won't print anything when the method is called when moving element in your table.

Also, I found someway to optimize your code a little bit.

You could replace:

```
if (!$res = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
       SELECT `id_quicklinks`, `position`
       FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
       ORDER BY `position` ASC'
))
    return false;

foreach ($res as $quicklinks)
    if ((int)$quicklinks['id_quicklinks'] == (int)$id)
         $moved_quicklinks = $quicklinks;
```

By :

```
if (!$moved_quicklinks  = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
       SELECT `id_quicklinks`, `position`
       FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
       WHERE `id_quicklinks` = ' . (int) $id . '
       LIMIT 1;'
))
    return false;
```

The fewer rows (and fields) returned by the database is the best. Moreover, it remove the need of a loop in your PHP code.

You could also merge both your update queries in the same database call:

```
return (Db::getInstance()->execute('
            UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
            SET `position`= `position` '.($way ? '- 1' : '+ 1').'
            WHERE `position`
            '.($way
                ? '> '.(int)$moved_quicklinks[0]['position'].' AND `position` <= '.(int)$position
                : '< '.(int)$moved_quicklinks[0]['position'].' AND `position` >= '.(int)$position.'
            ') . '; UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'quicklinks`
            SET `position` = '.(int)$position.'
            WHERE `id_quicklinks` = '.(int)$moved_quicklinks[0]['id_quicklinks']);
```

Database calls are costly operations, so reducing them to the minimum is a must. Like in your PHP code, the second query won't be executed if the first fails.

Here's how my `ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()` looks like:

```
public function ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()
{
    $id = (int) Tools::getValue('id');
    $positions = Tools::getValue("priority_level");
    $way = (boolean) Tools::getValue('way');

    //"and $id" because an ID of 0 is invalid (at least if you are using an auto-increment PK)
    if (is_array($positions) and $id)  
    {
        foreach ($positions as $position => $value)
        {
            $pos = explode('_', $value);

            if (isset($pos[2]) && (int) $pos[2] === $id)
            {
                $position = (int) $position;

                if ($priorityLevel = Db::getInstance()->executeS(
                        'SELECT `id_priority_level`, 
                            `priority_level`
                        FROM `pc_job_priority`
                        WHERE `id_priority_level` = ' . $id . '
                        LIMIT 1'
                )) {
                    Db::getInstance()->execute(
                        'UPDATE `pc_job_priority`
                        SET `priority_level` = `priority_level` '. 
                            ($way ? '- 1' : '+ 1') . '
                        WHERE `priority_level`' . (
                            $way ? 
                            ' > '. (int) $priorityLevel[0]['priority_level'] . 
                                ' AND `priority_level` <= '. $position :
                            ' < '. (int) $priorityLevel[0]['priority_level'] . 
                                ' AND `priority_level` >= '. $position 
                        ) . '; 
                        UPDATE `pc_job_priority`
                        SET `priority_level` = ' . $position . '
                        WHERE `id_priority_level` = ' . $id
                    );
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```