# Prestashop custom module draggable sort/order

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Please tell me why I have a " Declaration of BlockRealization::updatePosition($way, $position, $id) should be compatible with ModuleCore::updatePosition($id_hook, $way, $position = NULL)"

I have this code in module.php

A similar question was here 
[Prestashop custom admin module draggable sort/order not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221564/prestashop-custom-admin-module-draggable-sort-order-not-working)?

Under my code in module.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) exit;

class BlockRealization extends Module {

protected $_html = '';

public function __construct() {

$this->name = 'blockrealization';
$this->tab = 'front_office_features';
$this->version = '1.0.0';
$this->author = 'XXX';
$this->need_instance = 0;
$this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
$this->bootstrap = true;

parent::__construct();

$this->displayName = $this->l('Module realization');
$this->description = $this->l('Display realization on homepage.');
$this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?'); 
}

public function install() {
if (!parent::install() ||
    !$this->registerHook('displayHeader') ||
    !$this->registerHook('home') ||
    !$this->createTables()
)
    return false;
return true;
}

public function uninstall() {
if (!parent::uninstall() ||
    !$this->removeTable())
    return false;
return true;
}

protected function createTables() {

/* Realization */
$res = (bool)Db::getInstance()->execute('
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'realization` (
        `id_realization_slides` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `image_realization` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id_realization_slides`, `image_realization`)
    ) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
');

return $res;
}

protected function removeTable() {
if (!Db::getInstance()->Execute('DROP TABLE `'. _DB_PREFIX_ . 'realization`'))
    return false;
return true;
}

public function getContent() {

$output = null;

if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name)) {
    $errors = '';

    if ($_FILES) {

        $helper = new HelperImageUploader('realization_img');
        $files = $helper->process();

        if ($files) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {

                if (isset($file['save_path'])) {
                    if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($file['save_path']))
                    $errors = Tools::displayError('Limit');

                    if (!$errors) {
                        if (!ImageManager::resize($file['save_path'], dirname(__FILE__) . '/img/' . $file['name']))
                            $errors = Tools::displayError('error');
                        else {

                            $previous_file = Configuration::get('realization_img');
                            $file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/img/' . $previous_file;

                            if (file_exists($file_path))
                                unlink($file_path);


                            $realization['image_realization'] = $file['name'];
                            $realization['position'] = count($this->getAll());
                            if (!Db::getInstance()->insert('realization', $realization))
                                $errors = Tools::displayError('error');
                        }
                    }

                    unlink($file['save_path']);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($errors) 
        $output .= $this->displayError($errors);
    else 

        $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
}

$output .= $this->generateList();
$output .= $this->displayForm();

return $output;
}

public function displayForm() {

 // Init Fields form array
 $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
    'legend' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Add the realization'),
    ),
    'input' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'file',                              
            'label' => $this->l('Image:'),
            'name' => 'realization_img',
            'hint' => $this->l('Upload image for contact:'),
        )
    ),
    'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
    )
);

$helper = new HelperForm();

// Module, token and currentIndex
$helper->module = $this;
$helper->name_controller = $this->name;
$helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
$helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

// Title and toolbar
$helper->title = $this->displayName;
$helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
$helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
$helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
$helper->toolbar_btn = array(
    'save' =>
    array(
        'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
        'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
        '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
    ),
    'back' => array(
        'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
        'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
    )
);

// Load current value
$helper->tpl_vars = array(
    'fields_value' => array(
        'realization_img' => Configuration::get('realization_img')
    )
);

return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
}

public function generateList() {
$content = $this->getAll();

$fields_list = array(
    'id_realization_slides' => array(
        'title' => 'ID',
        'align' => 'center',
        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
    ),
    'image_realization' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Image'),
        'orderby' => false,
        'search' => false
    ),
    'position' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Position'),
        'position' => 'position' ,
        'orderby' => false,
        'search' => false
    ),
);

$helper = new HelperList();
$helper->shopLinkType = '';
$helper->actions = array('edit', 'delete');
$helper->module = $this;
$helper->listTotal = count($content);
$helper->identifier = 'id_realization_slides';
$helper->title = $this->l('Realizations');
$helper->table = $this->name;
$helper->imageType = 'jpg';
$helper->orderBy = 'position';
$helper->orderWay = 'asc';
$helper->position_identifier = 'id_realization_slides';
$helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
$helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

return $helper->generateList($content, $fields_list);
}

public function getAll() {
return Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
    SELECT *
    FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'realization
');
}

public function ajaxProcessUpdatePositions()
{
$way = (int)Tools::getValue('way');
$id_quicklinks = (int)Tools::getValue('id');
$positions = Tools::getValue('realization_slides');

if (is_array($positions))
    foreach ($positions as $position => $value)
    {
        $pos = explode('_', $value);

        if (isset($pos[2]) && (int)$pos[2] === $id_velcroquicklinks)
        {
                if (isset($position) && $this->updatePosition($way, $position, $id_quicklinks))
                    echo 'ok position '.(int)$position.' for id '.(int)$pos[1].'\r\n';
                else
                    echo '{"hasError" : true, "errors" : "Can not update id '.(int)$id_quicklinks.' to position '.(int)$position.' "}';

            break;
        }
    }

 }

public function updatePosition($way, $position, $id)
{

if (!$res = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
    SELECT `id_realization_slides`, `position`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'realization`
    ORDER BY `position` ASC'
))
    return false;

foreach ($res as $quicklinks)
    if ((int)$quicklinks['id_realization_slides'] == (int)$id)
        $moved_quicklinks = $quicklinks;

if (!isset($moved_quicklinks) || !isset($position))
    return false;

return (Db::getInstance()->execute('
    UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'realization`
    SET `position`= `position` '.($way ? '- 1' : '+ 1').'
    WHERE `position`
    '.($way
        ? '> '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['position'].' AND `position` <= '.(int)$position
        : '< '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['position'].' AND `position` >= '.(int)$position.'
    '))
&& Db::getInstance()->execute('
    UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'realization`
    SET `position` = '.(int)$position.'
    WHERE `id_realization_slides` = '.(int)$moved_quicklinks['id_quicklinks']));
 }

 public function hookHome($params) {

return $this->display(__FILE__, "views/templates/hook/realization.tpl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you extend the class Module and it already has the same method which you basically override. And in PHP 7+ if you want to override or extend method you have to declare the same parameters(even if they have default values in the parent class method) and the same access level. So you just need to follow the rule and use the same declaration or you can rename your method if it's not necessary to override/extend the parent class one(and it seems so)

Comment: Can you provide code or exemple? Where can I find how the method should looks like?

Comment: Having the same exact quantity of arguments with default values and the same visibility scope is important. For example, parentClass::customMethod($one, $two, $three = false) and childClass::customMethod($one, $two, $three) you'll get an error because arguments aren't the same, or if you'll miss one of them etc. The declaration has to be the same and if parentClass::customMethod is public/protected/private the childClass::customMethod has to have the same as well. So, childClass::customMethod($one, $two, $three = false) must to be like here